# How to convert a div with img tags to an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html2canvas

I am trying to convert a div containing some img tags to a png. After some search, it looks like the best way is to use the html2canvas library.

The problem is that it is not working for me and I don't understand why.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="lib/js/Blob.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/FileSaver.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/html2canvas.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <title>Tests Only</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="navigationButtons">
        </div>

        <div id="sourceScreen" style="width:200px">
            <img id="lol" src="tier-icons/base_icons/bronze.png" />
        </div>

        <div id="targetScreen">
        </div>

        <script = "text/javascript">
        jQuery('#navigationButtons').append('<button type="button" id="makeScreenshot">Screenshot</button>');
        jQuery('#makeScreenshot').click(makeScreenshot);

        function makeScreenshot(){
          html2canvas(jQuery('#sourceScreen'), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
              jQuery('#targetScreen').html(canvas);
            }
          });
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a jsFiddle of my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/2vv79ehy/1/

I am trying to get it work with 1 img tag first on this example, the goal is to display the canvas under the real image.
I know there is a problem with cross-domain resources with this library but when I do the test with my real code, the image is hosted on my computer.

Does anyone know how to do it or if there is another way (would be great if it could bypass cross-domain problems too)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSFiddle works, except for the cross-domain problem. I've played around trying to find a quick hack around it, but the best I could come up with is just drawing onto the canvas that you're given in your `onrendered` event and I haven't really played with positioning and the z-order would be impossible to implement this way, but maybe this edit to your `makeScreenshot` function helps you find a solution that works for you:

```js
function makeScreenshot(){
  html2canvas(jQuery('#sourceScreen'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var img = jQuery("#cat");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var originalPosition = { left: 0, top: 18 };
      ctx.drawImage(img[0],originalPosition.left,originalPosition.top);
      jQuery('#targetScreen').html(canvas);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: My jsFiddle works as-is or did you change something? I'm using chrome (can't download FF atm, I'll check that out tomorrow) and I just have an empty div.
I'll try the function you gave me and see if I can "make a screenshot" of the 2 previous images (original + its copy).
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @PineApple34 It works as-is in the sense that `html2canvas` makes a screenshot minus the image because it is in a different domain. You can verify this by adding text or something in the div you're making a screenshot of. The code I provided just takes the image and draws it onto the new canvas provided by `html2canvas` but it doesn't calculate the position in which to draw it in.

Comment: Well, I don't get it then because it is not working when the image is hosted on my computer (could there be a cross-domain error when everything is running on local?), I remember that I managed to 'screen' my menu-bar tho. Anyways, I gave up on this for now since I found a workaround (copying the content of my div full of img tags into another div then scale it) to my thumbnail issue.
I'm in a mood of developping several projects at once using different languages so I kinda pause a project every once in a while when I have an exciting idea for another one :p

Comment: @PineApple34 There could definitely be a cross-domain error when everything is local - if you're using file paths and not hosting on a server you're not using domains so that's definitely a cross-domain issue. I know the feeling :) Enjoy!

Comment: I ended up giving up on this function because I found some better functionnality to do for my program x)
Thank you for your help :)